# Where do I find a MySQL self-installer for OSX?

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, mysql5.5

I don't have the resources or know-how to install MySQL from source, and the downloads page on Mysql.com only provides versions that require lots of manual linking.

Isn't there anywhere that actually built MySQL to install in a Mac-friendly way? I've been looking for .dmg's, but Google isn't turning up anything useful.

Running OSX 10.6.7

EDIT: found it.

> http://mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.11-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg/from/http://mysql.mirrors.pair.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL.com does have .dmg files.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads) What do you mean by "requires lots of manual linking"?

If the .dmg file on MySQL.com doesn't work for you, then your best bet is probably to compile it yourself. Compiling stuff from source might sound daunting, but it's really not that hard. [Here's a pretty thorough tutorial that should help you out.](http://hivelogic.com/articles/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Just because it's possible, doesn't mean it's easy to do. One uses `apt` or `bundler` when they want to install a piece of code that will understand its targeted environment. Taking on every task from a "I'll just compile it from source" perspective is great when you're a sys op/admin, but a waste when you're just trying to setup a simple environment.

Comment: Shauna answered your question with the comment about dmg files. And letting someone know that compiling form source is an option and not as daunting is hardly a "I'll just compile it from source" perspective, but a legitimate response to your question. 

that being said, please mark Shauna's answer as correct so this question can be marked and finished

Comment: Thank you, rfelsburg. @nessur - I'm not saying that you should tackle every install probably with "I'll just compile it from source." I am a sysadmin and I still check the repositories for my Linux systems, or the software's website before I try compiling. If someone else has already done that legwork, it makes sense to use it. Sometimes, though, your only option is to compile yourself. When that does happen, it's good to know that it's actually not as hard as it might seem. Things like `make` or `dpkg` help ensure it's compiling for the proper environment.

Comment: likewise, please vote-up my question if you think it was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Having some experience with Linux Os'es, I found [macports](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP#mysql) to be a breeze and quick 'n' easy.

Comment: Thank you for not suggesting, also, that I compile mysql from source ;) Macports is pretty great.

Comment: gods above NO... If you're going into the line of work of building databases for scenarios then maybe I would suggest that. Why suggest a skill that, for most people, will only ever be done once every few years

Comment: @Dark Start - While nessur talks as if compiling is all I suggested, MySQL does put out a native Mac OS installer, which does work (I've used it). I merely suggested compiling as a last resort *if the native .dmg file doesn't work*, because it is still a valid option and while it's not as easy as double-clicking or dragging and dropping an installer, with tools like `make` it's generally not that terrible. The hardest part, I've found, is making sure you have the dependencies, but only because it's manual legwork.